# Reconnection Questions

Tags: java, http, sockets, tcp, mime

i have implemented  file upload code which uses a secure socket to upload files to a server using content-type Multipart Form-data to write the bytes.

Now and again I get a bad socket id error which through analysis in wireshark tells me that a fin packet is being sent from the server to the client for some reason. The identical code uploads 80% of the time so I dont think it is a bad format error so why would the server be disconnecting the connection when the content type states that there is moe data to be sent?

Anyways, If i cant solve the bad socket id issue would tcp/socket connections allow for a reconnection to resume the upload where it left off before disconnection.

Looking forward to insights on to this matter.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling flush on your socket? Sometimes you need to explicitly flush any remaining data otherwise "weird" behavior (i.e. not sending the last packet) can occur. Just an idea.

Comment: Hi, yes using flush after each wite. It's very intermittent but seems to occur on a write. I am uploading large ish files and would like to know a way to reconnect and resume upload if possible?